# How to set IntelliJ IDEA to keep tabs open even if file is deleted?

Tags: intellij-idea

I often place my tabs in an order I like, or ctrl-tab to recently used tabs. But then I temporarily checkout a branch in git in which those files are missing, and the tabs automatically disappear. Even in simpler editors such as notepad++, deleted files can be kept open in the editor. Can this be done in IntelliJ IDEA? Thanks.

(There seems to be no such option in the obvious File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no such option.

I typically use `ctrl-e` key very often, to re-open recently used files.

There is another option you could look at, and that is "restore workspace" configuration on switching branches.

You can try `settings` -> `version control` -> `Confirmation` -> `Restore workspace on branch switching` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I prefer the "recent tab" behaviour for ctrl-tab, so I swapped the keyboard shortcuts for "recent tab" and "switcher", i.e. ctrl-tab and ctrl-e, and that seems comfortable.